# Cannot save files to desktop in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-v1709

Everything was working fine until yesterday. Now, when I turned on my PC today and tried saving a text file written in Notepad, I am getting the following popup:

[image: Click here for the screenshot.]

Also, not just in saving txt files, I am having the same problem whenever I try to save images from photoshop or any files into the 'desktop'. However, everything just works fine when I try saving the same files in other drives. The problem occurs when I try saving the files in 'desktop', 'documents', 'pictures' or anything else that is a subfolder of C:\ drive. Morever, Microsoft Word or PDF files can be saved in the 'desktop' folder. Also, I can even download contents from the internet using Chrome directly to 'desktop'. The problem seems very crazy. I cannot simply figure out what's wrong with my PC.

Can anyone tell me the approach to fix this issue? I am thankful to you in advance.

[**P.S:** I am on Windows 10 OS v 1709.]

Comment: Complete guess but maybe the Security Essentials solution at the bottom of this thread will help? - - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-cant-save-stuff-to-the-desktop/21f1bdb7-6cbb-4bc2-92c8-d6a40e917588

Comment: You're welcome. Not a problem. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It was happening because I once turned on the **Controlled Folder Access** in Windows Defender which was by default turned off. I just opened the **Windows Defender Security Center >> Virus and threat Protection >> Virus and threat Protection settings >> "TURNED OFF" the *Controlled Folder Access***   option and it did my job. The problem was driving me nuts bdw. :(

Comment: I recently added all my drives to controlled folder access thinking it would help prevent unknown changes. Turns out it blocks all applications from changes! I was beating my head against the keyboard trying to figure out if my drive had bricked or not (stuck in read-only). This solved it.

Comment: I have had more problems with windows defender in the past month than I have ever had with any anti-virus program to this date. I wonder what has changed? Could a windows update be the sudden cause of my anti-virus issues? Anyway thank you for pointing out my Windows Defender "controlled folder access" issue. My problem is now fixed and I am a very happy camper.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of disabling it completely. I just allow specific applicatons through.

1. Click the windows button [image: Windows icon]
2. Type "Windows Security" and click on "Windows Security App" 
   [image: Windows Security App icon]
3. Click "Virus &Threat protection"

   [image: Virus and threat protection icon]
4. Scroll down (if necessary) and click "Manage ransomware protection"

   [image: Ransomware protection icon]
5. Click "Allow an app through Controlled folder access"

   [image: Allow an app through Controlled folder access]
6. Click "Yes" when the user account control pops up
7. Click "Add an allowed app"

   [image: Add an allowed app]
8. Choose between "Recently blocked apps" or "Browse all apps". I usually choose "Recently blocked apps"
9. Click the plus icon next to the app you want to allow

   [image: add icon]
10. Click the "Close" button
11. **Important: Restart the app if it was open. Otherwise it will not work (in my experience).**

Comment: Any ideas how to allow a specific python script through, rather than python.exe, which would allow any arbitrary python script access.

Comment: I think there was no option like this in the version that I used back then.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in this [Microsoft Forum question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-cant-save-stuff-to-the-desktop/21f1bdb7-6cbb-4bc2-92c8-d6a40e917588), Microsoft (MS) Security Essentials can apparently interfere with saving items to certain special "controlled" folders. The solution to alleviate this issues is to:

- From the Start Menu, select *Settings*. Click the *Update and Security* icon.
- Choose *Windows Defender* from the list of items on the left. Scroll to the very bottom in the right-hand pane and then click the *Open Windows Defender*/*Security Center* link.
- In the new window, select *Protection from Virus and Threats*  > *Virus and Threats Settings*.
- Turn off *Access to Controlled Folders*.

Comment: I did the same thing mate. Bdw voted ur answer as Correct. Cheers !!